# How to save a list of active records with virtual attribute and validate on that virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an active record with a virtual attribute :email and a class method :create_with_emails. Controller calls that method with a list of emails to create records. email is not a column in the corresponding table of that active record, I need to use another model to get user_id (user_id is a column in corresponding table) from that email and then save the record to the database. However, email provided by controller may not have a user_id. In that case, API should report that to frontend. API should return all emails without user_id in an error message. Want to know what's good practice to implement a feature like this? Some sample code of the model or controller will be very helpful. Thx!

Following is a simple version of the active record I have now, but I'm not sure what's a good way to validate emails and report that back to frontend.

```
class MyRecord < ActiveRecord
  def self.create_with_emails(emails)
    email_arr = emails.split(",")
    user_ids = User.where(email: email_arr).pluck(:user_id)
    bulk_insert(ignore: true) do |worker|
      user_ids.each do |user_id|
        worker.add(user_id: user_id, another_attr: another_attr)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Any relevant code you can share for what you have so far?

Comment: @MarkMerritt I added some code. Thx.